# SSRS 2005 - Add Static Column Header in a Matrix report

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

All my SSRS knowledge came to nothing, when I need to create a report in **SSRS 2005**.
I prepared a Matrix report. Class is grouped (In green).

See the images below.

Fig 1: This is what I am trying to create
[image]

Fig 2: This is what I have so far created.
[image]

**Question:**

1. Do we have static column Header option in SSRS 2005. (In 2008/2012 ,we add a row above and outside the group)?
2. Any ideas to bring the static header (Header in red colored part of the report)

*PS:
once again, I am looking for a solution in SSRS 2005*

```
Edit: 04/09

Session and Paper as a group on ROW
Class on Column group
Under Column group, Average, Class Max, Class Min and Attendance
```

Comment: Can you show your groupings for rows and columns?

Comment: @lethaljd, Will the edit be enough?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a good built-in way to do this properly and it seems microsoft fixed the issue in SSRS 2008.

one possible workaround is to add a Rectangle into the top-left cell of the matrix at first, and then add multiple textboxes in to it for displaying column headers.

Comment: Yes, Looks like it is the end of the road. the way you suggested was good, but there is one additional requirement, like an Interactive sort on one of the column headers. Due to that,this solution is also not enough.
Thanks anyway.